# Android SDK Samples Error

Tags: android, windows, sdk, sample

I'm trying to build any of the Android SDK samples on my windows machine in Eclipse.  I've created a new project, selected Android Sample Project and then tried to run them.  They compile fine (pre-compilation is on) but when it comes to running it cannot find the bin\resources.ap_ file which I think was meant to be created in the post-build step:

Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

I **have** tried to clean the project.

Here's the console output:

```
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Refreshing resource folders.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Starting full Pre Compiler.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Removing generated java classes.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Preparing generated java files for update/creation.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -m -v -J C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\gen -M C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\android.jar 
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Configurations:
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]  (default)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]  land
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]  port
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] 
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Files:
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   drawable\app_lunar_lander.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   drawable\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: (land) C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: (port) C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   drawable\lander_crashed.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   drawable\lander_firing.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_firing.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   drawable\lander_plain.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_plain.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   layout\lunar_layout.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\layout\lunar_layout.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   values\strings.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\values\strings.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   AndroidManifest.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\AndroidManifest.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] 
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Resource Dirs:
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   Type drawable
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     drawable\app_lunar_lander.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     drawable\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: (land) C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: (port) C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     drawable\lander_crashed.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     drawable\lander_firing.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_firing.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     drawable\lander_plain.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_plain.png
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   Type layout
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     layout\lunar_layout.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\layout\lunar_layout.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   Type values
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     values\strings.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]       Src: () C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\values\strings.xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Including resources from package: C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\android.jar
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for drawable
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for layout
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for anim
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for animator
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for interpolator
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for xml
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for raw
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for color
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for menu
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] applyFileOverlay for mipmap
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id app_lunar_lander from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id earthrise from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id earthrise from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id lander_crashed from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id lander_firing from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_firing.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id lander_plain from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_plain.png)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]     (new resource id lunar_layout from C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\layout\lunar_layout.xml)
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Starting full Package build.
[2011-11-15 15:11:55 - LunieLander] Skipping over Post Compiler.
[2011-11-15 15:12:04 - LunieLander] Refreshing resource folders.
[2011-11-15 15:12:04 - LunieLander] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2011-11-15 15:12:04 - LunieLander] Nothing to pre compile!
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Starting full Post Compiler.
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe crunch -v -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res -C C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res 
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] To destination dir: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable-land\earthrise.png: 93% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable-port\earthrise.png: 88% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\app_lunar_lander.png: 39% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_crashed.png: 66% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_firing.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_firing.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_firing.png: 65% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Processing image to cache: C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res\drawable\lander_plain.png => C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_plain.png
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander]   (processed image to cache entry C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res\drawable\lander_plain.png: 35% size of source)
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] Crunched 6 PNG files to update cache
[2011-11-15 15:12:12 - LunieLander] C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -v -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res -f --no-crunch --auto-add-overlay --debug-mode -M C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\AndroidManifest.xml -A C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\assets -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\android.jar -F C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\resources.ap_ 
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\LunarLander.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\LunarView$1.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\LunarView$LunarThread.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\LunarView.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R$attr.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R$drawable.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R$id.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R$layout.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R$string.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Dx processing C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\classes\.\com\example\android\lunarlander\R.class...
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Using default debug key to sign package
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Using keystore: C:\Users\matt\.android\debug.keystore
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Build Success!
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Refreshing resource folders.
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2011-11-15 15:12:29 - LunieLander] Nothing to pre compile!
[2011-11-15 15:50:26 - LunieLander] Starting full Post Compiler.
[2011-11-15 15:50:26 - LunieLander] C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -v -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\res -S C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\res -f --no-crunch --auto-add-overlay --debug-mode -M C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\AndroidManifest.xml -A C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\assets -I C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\android.jar -F C:\Users\matt\workspace\LunieLander\bin\resources.ap_ 
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Using default debug key to sign package
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Using keystore: C:\Users\matt\.android\debug.keystore
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Build Success!
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Refreshing resource folders.
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2011-11-15 15:50:43 - LunieLander] Nothing to pre compile!
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: You've attached output from multiple outputs (one build completed at 15:12:29, another starting at 15:50:26), unless your system is VERY slow and took 37 minutes and 57 seconds; the second one also went from Pre to Post compile and skipped the Package Build in between. Also, there's no indication of an error in the output you posted whatsoever. I'm not sure how we're supposed to help here...

Comment: LOL, sorry Ken, I should have been more careful.   You're right too, a lack of error message is nuts isn't it?  Anyway, after much searching I found the error:

Found it.  aapt.exe was crashing because the Eclipse Android Build preferences were set to be "verbose" - I changed this to normal and it built fine.  Whatever happened to descriptive error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  aapt.exe was crashing because the Eclipse Android Build preferences were set to be "verbose" - I changed this to normal and it built fine.